# Proving $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is closed, not open and not bounded metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

I'm working my way through the examples in Rudin on open sets, closed sets and other related material to get use to working with the definitions.

I'm trying to show that $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is closed, but not open and not bounded. My attempts are below.

**Closed**:

We want to show that $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ contains all of its limit points. Suppose that $p =(p_{1}, p_{2})$ is a limit point of $\mathbb{Z}$ and that $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ (say). Then $B_{\epsilon}(p) = \{(a,b): d((a,b), (p_{1},p_{2})) < \epsilon\}.$

For our given choice of $\epsilon, B_{\epsilon}(p) = p.$ Which contradicts the fact that $p$ is a limit point and therefore $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't have any limit points. Hence it is closed (it contains all of its limit points, because it doesn't have any!).

**NOT open**:

Consider the point $(0,0)$, and let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}.$ Then $B_{\epsilon}((0,0))$ doesn't contain any other points of $\mathbb{Z}$ other than the point $(0,0)$ itself. Hence it is not open.

Question: What should the distance function actually be for $B_{\epsilon}((0,0))$? I am presuming it is the Euclidean metric in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ i.e. we would be showing $\sqrt{(a-0)^{2} + (b-0)^{2}} < \epsilon$ for some $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}.$

**NOT bounded**:

If we have a metric space $(X,d)$ and $E \subseteq X$, Rudin defines a bounded set as follows

> $E$ is bounded if there is a real number $M$ and a point $q \in X$ such that $d(p,q) < M$ for all $p$ in $E$.

Am I correct that NOT bounded is therefore defined as follows:

> $E$ is not bounded is for all real numbers $M$ and all points $q \in X$, $d(p,q) \geq M$ for some $p$ in $E$

(I wasn't sure if its only the quantifiers that I swap)

I'm not too sure how to proceed. I was thinking I could maybe use the Archemedian property in someway, but because I'm in a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ I'm not sure if that approach will work. Similarly I can't use $\sup$ or $\inf$ as I'm in a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't $B_{\epsilon}(p)=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2:d((a,b),(p_1,p_2))<\epsilon\}.$ Why did you write $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}?$ Your solution has me confused whether you're talking about th subset $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}.$

Comment: @Yes I was just trying to convey that $a$ and $b$ are integers.

Comment: So your set is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}?$

Comment: No. It's just $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. I put two coordinates $(a,b)$ etc because I thought since I am dealing with a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ I need to have two coordiantes.

Comment: So your set $\mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}.$ Of course, you need an ordered pair when you talk about an element of $\mathbb{R}^2.$ In that case $B_{\epsilon}(p) \cap \mathbb{Z}=\{(a,0):d((a,0),(p_1,p_2))<\epsilon\}.$

Comment: What's the difference between having $B_{\epsilon}(p) = \{(a,b): d((a,b), (p_{1}, p_{2})) < \epsilon\}$ and $\{(a,0): d((a,0), (p_{1}, p_{2})) < \epsilon\}$? I don't understand why the second co-ordinate has to be $0$? i.e. $(a,0)$

Comment: You need some sensible way of putting $\mathbb{Z}$ inside $\mathbb{R}^2$ see my answer for example. When you write $(a,b)$ this is saying that you can let $a$ and $b$ range throughout $\mathbb{Z}$. Drawing a picture will show you that this is a lattice, not "dots on a line" like $\mathbb{Z}$ would be.

Comment: @Mathlearner $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}.$ When you want to talk about it as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2,$ you identify it is $\mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}.$ Every element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is an ordered pair. So technically if $n \in \mathbb{Z},$ then $n \notin \mathbb{R}^2.$ However $(n,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that we are using a sensible embedding of $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ (say by $n \mapsto (n, 0)$).

To your question about the metric. From context I would presume that the metric is the usual euclidean one (the claim is false if we take an arbitrary metric - consider the discrete metric which makes all subsets open!).

Your proofs of closedness and non-openness seem fine.

You are right to think the set is not bounded. What you want to show is

> Given any $M > 0$ and any $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$, there is some $a \in \mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $d(p, a) > M$.

To do this, suppose that $p = (x, y)$. Then $d(p, (n,0)) \geq |n - x|$, so if we choose some large $n$ so that $|n - x| > M$ we are done.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Where we have $d(p, (n,0)) > |n-x|$, is this because our distance function is $\sqrt{(n-x)^{2} +y^{2}}$?

Comment: @Mathlearner yes that is one way to see it, another way is via the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0):

I identify $\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$

**Closed**: Any converging sequence on $\mathbb{Z}$ must be eventually constant so this is trivial.

**Not open**: The ball $B_{\mathbb{R}^2}(0,\epsilon)$ always contains a non-integer.

**Not bounded**: A bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ lies in some ball $B_{\mathbb{R}^2}(0,r)$ with large enough radius. It is then clear that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not bounded.